# What is the origin of the "reverse" hagbah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, simchat-torah, hagbah-gelilah

I have seen in a few shuls people perform a "reverse" hagbah on Simchat Torah. The way this is done is that the person crosses his hands placing his right hand on the left *etz chayim* ("scroller") and the left hand on the right *etz chayim* while the Torah is on the table. Then. while lifting, he flips the hands around so that the writing is facing away from his body rather than towards it.

Why is this done, and what is the origin of this minhag? Is this actually allowed, halachically? Isn't there a halacha that the writing must face the lifter and / or when rolling the Torah closed, the writing must face the lifter?

Comment: Wouldn't it fall?

Comment: "Isn't there a halacha that the writing must face the lifter and / or when rolling the Torah closed, the writing must face the lifter?" I don't recall every hearing of one.

Comment: @DoubleAA Looks like dupe to me.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&st=&pgnum=457

Comment: I have only seen this done after Chatan Torah on Simchas Torah. That is it is done after V'zos Habracha is completed for that sefer Torah only.